# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS excluding one sup domain and add www if needed

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, https

I want to redirect my SSL site (`domain.com`) with HTTPS protocol but not `domain.org` which is actually a sub-directory of `domain.com` (`domain.com/domainorg/`).  I want this:

- `http://domain.com` TO `https://www.domain.com`
- `http://domain.org` TO `http://www.domain.org`

I tested my htacess on http://htaccess.mwl.be/ and it works fine but when I actually run it, I get “The page isn't redirecting properly” and it appears to be in a loop when I test all options.

This is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.org$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I am not proficient at htacess at all.  What do I need to correct or change?

Answer (score 1):

Why are some of your rules outside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`? I'd put all of them inside it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirecting domain.com http URLs to https (any non-www will be rewritten to www as well)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  # Redirecting domain.com non-www domain.com URLs to www (any non-https will be rewritten to https as well)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

  # Redirecting domain.org non-www URLs to www (any https will be rewritten to http as well)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.org$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]

  # Redirecting domain.org https URLs to http (any non-www will be rewritten to www as well)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.org$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

You may also force URLs like this `domain.com/domainorg/*` to be redirected to `http://www.domain.org/*` using:

```
  RewriteCond RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?domainorg(\/.*)?$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.org%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You are missing the `domain.org` to `http://www.domain.org` redirect. (You probably don't need/want the `<IfModule>` container at all in this instance.)

Comment: Right, i missed the domain.org rewrite. However i don't see why you'd put some `RewriteCond`s and `RewriteRule`s outside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and other ones inside it.

Comment: Yes, in this case, it doesn't make sense to have some directives inside and some outside the `<IfModule>` container. However, I was just suggesting that the `<IfModule>` container probably shouldn't be used at all here. "I'd put all of them inside it." - I would simply remove it. :)

Comment: Your last `RewriteRule` (in the first block) will redirect `https://www.domain.com` to `http://www.domain.org`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, i just updated my answer.

Comment: I just realized that for the script on a page to work, I need that page to not be HTTPS.  The format would be `www.domain.com/sub/page.html`.  What code do I add?